# npm install this command not working in laravel

Tags: npm, npm-install

**Output of npm install**

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\krushikranti>npm install

up to date, audited 768 packages in 6s

80 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

7 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.

C:\xampp\htdocs\krushikranti>
```

Comment: It clearly says that your folder is up to date with required npm packages. What's the issue?

Comment: This shows no error message. Can you describe what the problem is? I have also changed the tags from laravel to npm, because this has nothing to do with Laravel.